# Insert two or more pieces of data into a database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to insert two or more pieces of data into a database but it doesn't work. Here is my `Databasehelper` class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String CreateTABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            COL1_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2_Barcode + " TEXT" +
            COL3_Time + " TEXT)";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CreateTABLE);
}

public boolean insertData(String barcodecontent, String systemtime) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2_Barcode, barcodecontent);
    contentValues.put(COL3_Time, systemtime);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Here is my `IncomingActivity` class:

```
public void AddData() {
    boolean isInserted = myDB.insertData(incoming_brc_textview.getText().toString(), incoming_hide_time.getText().toString());
    if (isInserted == true) {
        Toast.makeText(IncomingActivity.this, incoming_brc_textview.getText().toString() + "  store success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(IncomingActivity.this, incoming_brc_textview.getText().toString() + "  store failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated what error you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `CreateTable` query to this:

```
 String CreateTABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
        TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        COL1_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COL2_Barcode + " TEXT, " +
        COL3_Time + " TEXT)";
```

It seems like you've forgotten a comma in your query.

Comment: Hi Razor, It works, after I've added the comma in my table,

Comment: I'm very appreciate your help, the problem was confused my 5 day!!! Thanks again!! :)